# The syntax of the command is incorrect when not run from cmd line

Tags: for-loop, syntax, batch-file, cmd, task

I have a batch file that runs fine if I run it from the command prompt, but throws an error if it's called from Task Scheduler or run through Explorer. It appears that the syntax error occurs with the FOR logic.

```
@echo off

del mic_car*.txt

ftp -i -s:car_ftp_script.txt

pause

for /F %%I in ('dir /b/os mic_car*.txt') do (
  echo %%I
  pause
  set tempfile=%%I
  if exist %tempfile% (
    del car_report.txt
    ren %tempfile% car_report.txt
  ) 
)

del mic_car*.txt
copy /y car_report.txt ..\car_report.txt

pause
```

If I run this from explorer or Task Scheduler, I see the files being transferred via FTP, followed by the syntax error. If I run it via command line, I see the echo of each file being processed and the largest file is copied to the higher level directory.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your code cannot be working properly, even from the command line.

Your problem is your setting of `tempfile` and expansion of `%tempfile%` from within the same block of code. The value is expanded when the line is parsed, and all lines of the FOR statement are parsed in one pass. So your IF and REN statements are seeing the value that existed prior to entry of the loop.

Your code fails with a syntax error when `tempfile` is not defined. After expansion, the IF statement becomes invalid: `if exist  ( ...`, hence the error.

The reason you think it works from the command line is because you probably ran the code once and it failed, but when finished, the `tempfile` variable is set, so the script will appear to run OK the next time you run it.

Normally I recommend the use of delayed expansion to enable setting and expanding a variable within a loop. But you don't have any reason to use `tempfile` at all - just use the FOR variable directly.

```
@echo off

del mic_car*.txt

ftp -i -s:car_ftp_script.txt

for /F %%I in ('dir /b/os mic_car*.txt') do (
  echo %%I
  if exist "%%I" (
    del car_report.txt
    ren "%%I" car_report.txt
  ) 
)

del mic_car*.txt
copy /y car_report.txt ..\car_report.txt

pause
```

Actually, I don't understand why you need IF at all since your FOR loop only returns existing files. And all mic_car*.txt files will have been renamed car_report.txt (last one wins), so there should not be any need for your final DEL command.

You can combine the DEL and REN commands into one command by using MOVE

```
@echo off

del mic_car*.txt

ftp -i -s:car_ftp_script.txt

for /F %%I in ('dir /b/os mic_car*.txt') do (
  echo %%I
  move /y "%%I" car_report.txt >nul
)

copy /y car_report.txt ..\car_report.txt

pause
```

Comment: Well, there you have it! It must have been working because it had been run twice... I've never done much with batch files, and this information was really helpful!

Answer (score 1):

What version of Windows are you using?

I've changed the script to call a subroutine with the data extracted from your directory listing.

```
@echo off

del mic_car*.txt

ftp -i -s:car_ftp_script.txt

pause

for /F %%I in ('dir /b/os mic_car*.txt') do call :blue %%I
goto exit

:blue
  echo -- processing %1 -------------
  pause
  set tempfile=%1
  if exist %tempfile% (
    del car_report.txt
    ren %tempfile% car_report.txt
    echo -- renamed %tempfile% to car_report.txt -------------
  ) 


del mic_car*.txt
copy /y car_report.txt ..\car_report.txt
echo -- finished %1 -------------
pause

goto :eof

:exit
```

There is a difference in default directory between Windows Explorer and Scheduler, and for that reason, you should consider using explicit paths to the files and directories in which your object files are found. eg **del c:\carfiles\mi_car*.txt**, etc.

Answer (score 0):

These lines are the cause of your error:

```
set tempfile=%%I
if exist %tempfile% (
```

`%`-Variables are expandet at parse time, i.e. when the command (in this case the for loop) is parsed by the interpreter. At this point, the loop variable doesn't have a value, so `%tempfile%` is empty, thus causing the error.

You need to enable delayed expansion and use `!`-variables inside the loop. These variables are expanded at runtime, when the loop variable contains actual values.

```
setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion

for /F %%I in ('dir /b/os mic_car*.txt') do (
  echo %%I
  pause
  set tempfile=%%I
  if exist !tempfile! (
    del car_report.txt
    ren !tempfile! car_report.txt
  ) 
)
```